# Minecraft: How do i test for if a player has moved even the slightest bit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

ok so, I'm making a map and I need to make a system where if the player is not in an exact spot, something will happen, like heres the example.
          [image]
X=gold;where player is standing, I need it so  if player is facing the hopper and presses D they turn right 90* to stone and so one with every block, same if they hit A, just vice versa. Does that makes sense what I'm asking? I hope it does, I just want it so if a player hits D they will turn right 90* each time, but not move from X and vice versa with A.

Comment: basically what you could do is place an armorstand in the exact middle and then an armorstand in each direction that is VERY close to the middle one. then depending on what armorstand the player is closest to you can execute your rotations (and teleport the player back to the middle one afterwards)

Comment: but how would I do that with the command you cant combine the @e and @p syntax together... right? or could you use the execute command like this, /execute @a ~ ~ ~ /testfor @e[type=ArmorStand,r=.5]?

Comment: of course you can do that. what you can't do is r=0.5. also, as of 1.11 `ArmorStand` was changed to `armor_stand`

Comment: then how do I do it, if I cant do r=.5, I just need it so if the player moves to the left AT ALL, even the slightest bit, they will turn left 90*, and the same for moving right, what is the command to do this? I can't seem to figure it out. Plz help...

Comment: how would I do this then, I just need to test for if the player moves even the slightest bit in one direction

Comment: Read the answer of CommanderRedstone. He knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've been working on a map with this for 4 months so I think I'm an expert xD

So first, where the player is going to be, summon an armor stand with the name "Center" and the tag "Movement".

Next, summon an armor stand 0.00000000001 north with then name "North" and the tag "Movement"

Do that for East, South and West.

Command block part:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players tag @e[r=1,c=1,tag=Movement] add Closest
/execute @e[name=North,tag=Closest] ~ ~ ~ /say North
/execute @e[name=East,tag=Closest] ~ ~ ~ /say East
/execute @e[name=South,tag=Closest] ~ ~ ~ /say South
/execute @e[name=West,tag=Closest] ~ ~ ~ /say West
/execute @e[tag=Closest,name=!Center] ~ ~ ~ /tp @p @e[c=1]
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=Movement] remove Movement
```

and if you want the player to look straight down, don't fall into the trap I did because you will suffer for 4 months xD

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add ML

/scoreboard players tag @a[rx=90,rxm=90,ry=90,rym=90] remove ML

/tp @a[tag=ML] ~ ~ ~ 90 90
```

Comment: ok so first off, I'm making this easier by just using left and right not north south east west. So basically, I have it set up, its just the commands you have provided don't work even changing the name=. keep in mind I am doing this in 1.10.2, so I looked it up and I didn't find anything. I just need to find the Armor stand closest to me, simple, now how do I do that?

Comment: Could you give me the exact commands you used for detection AND the commands you used to spawn the armor stands?